# About the gradient descent update rule

Tags: convex-optimization, gradient-descent

When deriving the gradient descent algorithm the following function comes up
$$
f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(z-x) + \frac{1}{2t}\| z-x\|^2_2
$$
that when minimizing leads to the update rule $x - t \nabla f(x)$.
Where the term $\frac{1}{2t}\| z-x\|^2_2$ comes from?

I think it comes from a Taylor expansion:

$$
f(z) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(z-x) + \frac{1}{2}(z-x)^T\nabla^2 f(\theta (x-z) + z)(z-x),
$$
where $0 \leq \theta \leq 1$, but for this equation to match the previous one, it would be required to write
$$
\nabla^2 f(\theta (x-z) + z) = \frac{1}{t} I,
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Any direction $-H^{-1} \nabla f(x)$ with $H$ positive definite is a descent direction for $f$. In particular, we can take the Newton direction ($H = \nabla^2 f(x)$) that captures the curvature of the function, or the gradient descent direction ($H = I$ or a multiple thereof).

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed right about the origin of that term, see also the explanation provided here on paragraph 5.1:

[http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~ryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/05-grad-descent-scribed.pdf](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-S15/scribes/05-grad-descent-scribed.pdf)